# automatic new mac setup (dotfiles, scripts, etc)

Tags: macos, mac, script, shell-script, applescript

I'm looking for a way to automate the setup of a new macbook I'm about to purchase. I've done through quite a few during the years and it always takes forever to get everything up properly. I don't want any of the old files as I will be backing them up, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to set up a build process for any new macs I end up purchasing in the future.

Looking for advice on what method I should take to automate this sort of thing, whether it be a shell script or applescript or anything else.

A quick overview of the things I have setup on my mac that i'd like the be able to reinstall on a new machine automatically:

- Remap my caps lock to quicksilver/spotlight (keyremap4macbook)
- all my dotfiles
- node, rails, rvm, etc
- other terminal utilities/settings
- general shorcuts I've set up for applications like nvAlt
- sublime with all my packages
- all general settings from system preferences
- all my other applications and their settings
- apache/mysql/virtual host

I'm looking for something along these lines, but with more support for general osx settings/applications: https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles

Comment: Did you try simply Migrating the old machine to the new, then see what's missing? The chances are it will be very little.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you ask for are covered in the **dotfiles** repository of Nicolas Gallagher, that I find quite useful: https://github.com/necolas/dotfiles

A lot of OS X and Apple Application settings (desktop environment behaviour, spotlight/finder/etc settings...) can be configured via command line using the *defaults* tool, take a look at this file from the repository I mentioned: https://github.com/necolas/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/osxdefaults

Installing 3rd party desktop applications can be automated most of the time using *brew cask*.

In addition, you might also want to take a look at **boxen**, a tool using puppet to automate the setup of macs that has been developed and is used at GitHub: https://boxen.github.com/